# Does the function $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)$ have a limit of 1 as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ and is it continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits

I tried approaching the origin along the x-axis (y = 0), the y-axis (x = 0), and the line y = x. All three answers gave me 1 but I do not know if that is enough or if I am missing a path that gives a value other than 1. Would an existing limit of 1 confirm whether or not the function is continuous at (0,0)

I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: I dont get it, is the function just equal to $1$ ?

Comment: Yes, as @Rene says, but more specifically this function is $1$ at all points other than $(0,0)$, but undefined there. [however for limits, the value or definedness *at* the approached point is irrelevant.

Comment: @coffeemath Then define  $f(0,0) = 1$ and the limit is trivial equal to 1!

Comment: @Winther ummm, no.  Just because $f(a) = b$ does not mean that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = b$.

Comment: @coffeemath Look: if $f(0,0)=1$ then $f=1$ everywhere!

Comment: @Winther why is it necessary to define $f(0,0)$ at all? The definition of limit does not depend on that being defined, or what its value is if defined.

Comment: Sorry that last comment was to @anorton

Comment: @coffeemath My point: If it does not matter then for simplicity take $f(0,0) = 1$ and the limit follows trivially  as $f=1$ everywhere.

Comment: This question is like asking: "Why is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1$?" It doesn't matter that it's undefined at $0$ because that's not how the limit works. It means "as $x$ gets _arbitrarily close_ to $0$, what is $\frac{x}{x}$?"

Comment: @Winther Oh, ok.  I agree with that.  At first, I thought you were saying "If you have a function that's undefined at a point $P$, and we make $f(P) = 1$, then the limit is $1$ all the time!"  (Which is clearly not what you meant, now that I take a second look.)

Comment: Limit: yes. Continuous: no, since, to be continuous at some point, a function must be defined at this point and (apparently) the function f is not defined at (0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $f(x, y) = 1$ everywhere except $(0, 0)$.  Since the limit doesn't depend on the actual point, but only on the points "around" the "target" point, it is clear that the limit is $1$.

If you can't see the above intuitively, you can use the substitution $x=r \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2 + y^2} &= \lim_{(r, \theta)\to(0, 0)}\frac{(r\sin(\theta))^2 + (r\cos(\theta))^2}{(r\sin(\theta))^2 + (r\cos(\theta))^2} \\
&=\lim_{(r, \theta)\to(0, 0)}\frac{r^2(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))}{r^2(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))} \\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2}{r^2} \\
&=1 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2}=1\ 
\mbox{if}\ (x,y)\neq(0,0)$$
So, it is just a constant function  defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus(0,0)$: the limit is obviously 1, but it doesn't make sense to consider continuity in $(0,0)$ since the function is not defined in that point (hence you cannot compare the value of the function in $(0,0)$ with the limit).

What you can ask is "Is there a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ whose restriction to $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus(0,0)$ coincide with $f$?" In this case the answer is yes: the constant function $g(x,y)=1$.